# Вывод данных с 4 таблиц mysql

Tags: mysql

Не могу решить одну проблему, надо с mysql вытащить данные которые лежат в одной таблице, но исходные данные совсем другие.
Есть таблица local_auth_account_journal с полями account_id  balance где мне по веденным данным надо вытащить баланс по account_id, вводят номер карты который лежит в trm_in_cards start_card_code (но она такого вида 99999000086922, а ввожу я последние 5 только) получаю id и по этому id который равен card в таблице trm_in_card_client и беру оттуда client который равно params в таблице local_auth_account и где по account_type_id=33 нахожу id который вот равен account_id

Пытался так, но вроде как чушь

```
SELECT `local_auth_account_journal`.account_id AS `local_auth_account`.id, `local_auth_account_journal`.balance, `local_auth_account_journal`.id, `trm_in_cards`.start_card_code, `trm_in_cards`.id AS `trm_in_card_client`.card, `trm_in_card_client`.client AS `local_auth_account`.params, 
`local_auth_account`.account_type_id  
FROM `local_auth_account` , `trm_in_card_client` , `trm_in_cards` , `local_auth_account_journal` 
WHERE `trm_in_cards`.start_card_code=99999000086922 
AND `local_auth_account`.account_type_id=33 
AND `local_auth_account_journal`.account_id=`local_auth_account`.id 
AND `trm_in_cards`.id AS `trm_in_card_client`.card 
AND `trm_in_card_client`.client AS `local_auth_account`.params
```

а мне надо в `trm_in_cards`.start_card_code  ввести 5 цифр и вытащить баланс с `local_auth_account_journal`.balance

сама таблица https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=988bee7872966a3c660e2c205b0acd4a
Ну и скриншотом чтобы было понятной
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выложите (кодом, как текст, не картинками!) CREATE TABLE для обеих таблиц, INSERT INTO с примером данных (по 3-5 записей), покажите критерий отбора (те самые 5 цифр) и требуемый результат для показанных данных и критерия.

Comment: @Akina upd наверно этого достаточно будет?

Comment: А где *INSERT INTO с примером данных (по 3-5 записей)* и *критерий отбора (те самые 5 цифр) и требуемый результат для показанных данных и критерия*? Ну, допустим, критерий возьмём из *99999000086922, а ввожу я последние 5 только*, т.е. `'86922'`, но где тестовые данные и требуемый результат?

Comment: @Akina вот скинул, у меня там просто очень много данных, я рандомно взял по 10 примеров

Comment: **алиасы** и нормальное **форматирование** хотя бы можно использовать в запросе? чтобы его прочесть можно было не ломая глаза?

Comment: ведь если отформатировать то сразу будет видно что в последних двух строчках  действительно чушь. причем не какая-то особо сложная, а просто левая отсебятина. что значит `trm_in_cards.id AS trm_in_card_client.card? каким местом тут AS? почему нельзя написать условие ПО ОБРАЗУ предыдущих?

Comment: @Akina ну как то так

Comment: @Ипатьев был бы опыт сделал бы, сейчас я только изучаю

Comment: Всё равно не вижу требуемого ответа для показанных данных. Равно как в упор не вижу связей между таблицами (FOREIGN KEY). PS. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f12304335a7530b0fc3d6511b5249f50

Comment: @Akina ну там просто сотни тысяч данных, я могу взять пример конкретно одной карты, я просто скинул первые 10 который были в списке с каждой таблицы, там связи наверно не наблюдаются, сейчас сделаю

Comment: Не, я в упор не понимаю... Вы что, правда хотите, чтобы **МЫ** придумали Вам и логику связывания, и правильный ответ?

Comment: @Akina да я не говорю сделайте за меня, как куда копать же спрашиваю, вы начали говорить скиньте данные я вот и сижу пытаюсь скинуть данные чтобы хоть как то понять куда двигаться, честное слово почитал разные ссылки не хватило ума видимо понять из приведенных примеров потому что там на примерах про две таблицы говорят, а у меня 4, поэтому тут и ищу ответа как сделать правильно

Comment: @Akina вот добавил картинку где должно быть понятно

Comment: *там связи наверно не наблюдаются* Ну да, а Вы их тем не менее описываете... *я просто скинул первые 10 который были в списке с каждой таблицы* А надо взять не первые попавшиеся, а соответствующие друг другу.

Comment: Вы дайте чётко: значение поля А в таблице Б должно быть равно значению поля В в таблице Г - и так опишите связи для всех 4 таблиц. На скриншоте более-менее просматриваются `trm_in_cards.id = trm_in_card_client.card` и `trm_in_card_client.client = local_auth_account.params`, в тексте запроса ещё указано `local_auth_account_journal.account_id = local_auth_account.id`. Однако соответствующий запрос [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8dad8cfd1909e0f1f0706da698ccc90b) даёт пустой набор записей - т.е. исходные данные как были "не очень", так и остались.

Comment: Возьмите несколько записей (2-3) из trm_in_cards. Потом несколько строго соответствующих им (а не случайных) из trm_in_card_client (по 2-3 достаточно), затем так же из local_auth_account и local_auth_account_journal.

Comment: @Akina вот закинул две карты для примера

Comment: Ну-ка глянь [вот это](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6c0f361c504adc0373991673440c1e57)...

Comment: @Akina да работает круто, но время запроса 584 секунды. теперь вопрос как это оптимизировать)

Comment: @Akina есть еще одна проблема, при поиске она случайно подхватила другие данные, там был номер телефона в конце ровно с таким же значением а карты у нас с 999990000  начинаются

Comment: Точная версия MySQL - какая? Проблему "ещё одного телефона" решить не получится, придётся либо использовать полный номер при отборе, либо потом смотреть глазами. Правда, я как-то не понял, при чём тут телефон, если мы отбираем по номеру карты.

Comment: @Akina 5.6.17 версия

Comment: Попробуй вот в такой форме: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e16827d6660014ff468a7ab326d7e65f). Желательно наличие индекса `local_auth_account_journal (account_id, action_date, balance)`, и в остальных таблицах по полям связывания.

Comment: @Akina вроде теперь отлично, добавил еще такое условие WHERE tic.start_card_code LIKE '9%69953' AND laa.account_type_id=33;   20-30 секунд, хотелось бы побыстрее, но это уже чтото

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, там подъём по цепочке "волочёт" не так уж и много записей... сколько уникальных account_id присутствует в таблице local_auth_account_journal?

Comment: @Akina более 200т. спасибо вам я немного разобрался в этом дописал так чтобы выводилось быстрее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо Akina за помощь, несколько дней мучения и написал нужный мне запрос, а главное немного улучшил свои знания

```
SELECT laaj.balance from local_auth_account_journal  laaj
JOIN (SELECT account_id, MAX(action_date) action_date
  FROM local_auth_account_journal laaj
 WHERE
 account_id = (
 SELECT id From local_auth_account  WHERE 
account_type_id = 33 
and
params = (
select client from trm_in_card_client WHERE card = (select id from trm_in_cards WHERE start_card_code like '9%69953')))
GROUP BY account_id ) maxdataaddaccid 
USING(account_id,action_date)
```